# Alternate for nested ifelse with character columns in R

Tags: r

My df has a comments column and I need to search for multiple names in the comments using key words(he comment has a lot of irrelevant information and not necessarily full name provided) - able o accomplish this with nested ifelse but there is a limit of 50 for nesting and my list has grown to more than 200 names so the code looks very tedious and I don't want to be editing the code each time (instead i want to upload an excel with list of names and key search terms)

I am currently using this statement - which should give clear understanding of what the relevant columns contain

```
comdata$name <- ifelse(grepl('jen',comdata$comments),'Jennifer A',
                         ifelse(grepl('rick',final_DM$comments) | grepl('richard',final_DM$comments) ,'richard',
                                ifelse(grepl('summ',comdata$comments),'Summer','Others'))))
```

Is it possible to do this with a loop or some other way if I create a list of the names and the possible 'key' search terms?
basically i need the correct syntax to write below code - which just gives other for most of the rows in comdata$name:

```
 comdata$name< - ifelse(comdata$comments %like% name_list$Key.1, name_list$FullName, 'Other')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a key/val dataset and use `regex_left_join`

```
keyval <- data.frame(comments = c("jen", "rick"),
                     name = c("Jennifer A", "richard"))
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(comdata, keyval, by = "comments")
```